# Would a faster processor or more cores reduce Blazor compile times more?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Blazor and I'm used to recompiling quickly to see changes coming from MVC / API development. I have a 10850 Intel 10c CPU now with a Gen 4 NVME SSD, would going to a higher core CPU lower times or would I need to go with a higher clock speed CPU?

I've disabled some extensions in Visual Studio and I am using Edge as the default browser.